# Android: Get passed time of a normal CountDownTimer?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

Is there a way to save the exact passed time (either milliseconds, seconds or minutes is fine) of a `CountDownTimer`?

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
}.start();
```

I tried increasing a variable in `onTick()`, but the problem is, my timer is cancel and restartable over a Button, and `onTick()` gets called everytime I start the timer, no matter if a second passed or not. So if I click the Button multiple times in 1 second, `onClick()` gets called every single click, rather than once per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use System.currentTimeMillis(), is this what you are after?

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    long timeStart;

    public MyCountDownTimer(long x, long y) {
        super(x, y);
        timeStart =   System.currentTimeMillis();

    }


    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long timeLapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStart;
        /// your code
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        /// your code
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that works. However, my question is obsolete now because i dont need that anymore. I hope other finds that answer helpful tho.